# Best practices setting onSubscribe thread from an API

Tags: rx-java2

Let's say I have an API that exposes two methods, each returns an observable

```
import org.assertj.core.util.VisibleForTesting;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.Scheduler;

class SomeApiClass {

    private static final String[] doOnSubscribeThread = new String[1];

    static Observable<Integer> immediatelyDoWork() {
        return Observable.just(1, 2)
                .doOnSubscribe(ignore -> doOnSubscribeThread[0] = Thread.currentThread().getName())
                .flatMap(ignore -> doWork());
    }

    static Observable<Integer> periodicallyDoWork() {
        // interval is using default computation scheduler
        return Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .doOnSubscribe(ignore -> doOnSubscribeThread[0] = Thread.currentThread().getName())
                .flatMap(ignore -> doWork());
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    static String getSubscribedOnThread() {
        return doOnSubscribeThread[0];
    }

    private static Observable<Integer> doWork() {
        return Observable.create(emitter -> {
            Random random = new Random();
            emitter.onNext(random.nextInt());
            emitter.onComplete();
        });
    }
```

Most APIs would just let the calling application set the `subscribeOn` thread (imagine these tests are my application):

```
import org.junit.Test;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.observers.TestObserver;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat;

public class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void canSetSubscribeOnThread() {
        Observable<Integer> coloObservable = SomeApiClass.immediatelyDoWork()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

        TestObserver<Integer> testObserver = coloObservable.test();
        testObserver.awaitCount(2); // wait for a few emissions

        assertThat(SomeApiClass.getSubscribedOnThread()).contains("RxNewThreadScheduler");
    }

    @Test
    public void canSetSubscribeOnThreadIfApiUsesInterval() {
        Observable<Integer> coloObservable = SomeApiClass.periodicallyDoWork()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

        TestObserver<Integer> testObserver = coloObservable.test();
        testObserver.awaitCount(2); // wait for a few emissions

        assertThat(SomeApiClass.getSubscribedOnThread()).contains("RxNewThreadScheduler");
    }
}
```

IIUC in the `immediate` example all subscription side-effects (including `just()`) will happen on a new thread. [Karnok explains well here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5459#issuecomment-312423783).

But in the `periodic` example, `interval` will use the default (computation) scheduler. What do most APIs do in this case? Do they let the caller set subscribeOn thread for all subscription side-effects *except* `interval` itself? In the `periodic` test above, we are still able to set subscribeOn thread for everything but `interval`. Or do they add an argument to set this subscribeOn too:

```
/**
 * Works like {@link #periodicallyDoWork()} but allows caller to set subscribeOnSchedueler
 */
static Observable<Integer> periodicallyDoWork(Scheduler subscribeOnScheduler) {
    return Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, subscribeOnScheduler)
            .doOnSubscribe(ignore -> doOnSubscribeThread[0] = Thread.currentThread().getName())
            .flatMap(ignore -> doWork());
}
```

And then allow callers to omit the subscribeOn() method:

```
@Test
public void canSetSubscribeOnThreadIfApiUsesInterval() {
    Observable<Integer> coloObservable = SomeApiClass.periodicallyDoWork(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    TestObserver<Integer> testObserver = coloObservable.test();
    testObserver.awaitCount(2); // wait for a few emissions

    assertThat(SomeApiClass.getSubscribedOnThread()).contains("RxNewThreadScheduler");
}
```

Is this overkill? As long as the caller also calls subscribeOn() is there any danger in just letting `interval` use the default computation scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, an API that creates observer chains **must** provide ways of injecting schedulers. Without that capability, unit testing becomes almost impossible to manage.

I have quite a bit of experience writing tests for real time systems. Simply being able to supply a `TestScheduler` or two to the unit under test makes the difference between being able to test reasonably and not bothering. Consider a subsystem that has a `debounce()` method period of 1 second. It is not feasible to write unit tests of several dozen cases without being able to use a `TestScheduler` and using `advanceTimeBy()` to control the clock. This means unit tests can be done in 10s of milliseconds that would take minutes if using a regular scheduler.